# How to implement abstract class in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm new in Kotlin and I need to create 2 date ranges. One that shows the dates as they are created in the constructor and another that modifies the end date with a default date in case it is null or greater than the default date.
For this I had thought to create an abstract class with a start and end date and then create 2 data classes to implement this abstract class and put this business rule in one of them.
This is the code I have so far:

```
abstract class BaseLocalDateRange (
    open val startDate: LocalDate?,
    open val endDate: LocalDate?
    )

data class LocalDateRange(
    override val startDate: LocalDate?,
    override val endDate: LocalDate?
): BaseLocalDateRange(
    startDate,
    endDate
)

data class LocalDateRangeEndDate(
    override val startDate: LocalDate?,
    override val endDate: LocalDate?
): BaseLocalDateRange(
    startDate,
    if (endDate== null || endDate > LocalDate.of(2099, 12, 31)) LocalDate.of(2099, 12, 31) else endDate
)
```

My questions are:

- Is this ok or there is a better way to approach this problem?
- I would like to have the "default date" in properties and use it here, but I don't really know how, so if someone has an idea of how to handle this it would be great.

Thank you!

Comment: Please define what a "better" way means.

Comment: "I would like to have the 'default date' in properties" What properties? You mean a file stored somewhere? Or a named constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no you don't neet to override startDate and endDate

and you can DEFAULT_END_DATE at companion

```
package org.example

import java.time.LocalDate

abstract class BaseLocalDateRange(
    protected val startDate: LocalDate?,
    protected val endDate: LocalDate?
){
    companion object{
        val DEFAULT_END_DATE: LocalDate = LocalDate.of(2099, 12, 31)
    }
}


class LocalDateRange(startDate: LocalDate?, endDate: LocalDate?) : BaseLocalDateRange(startDate, endDate)

class LocalDateRangeEndDate(startDate: LocalDate?, endDate: LocalDate?) : BaseLocalDateRange(
    startDate,
    if (endDate!=null && endDate > DEFAULT_END_DATE) DEFAULT_END_DATE else endDate
)
```